# 'Must be real number, not str' Issue

Tags: python, rdkit

I am trying to compute dielectric constant of molecules using code from Research Gate (DOI: 10.1039/C9CP01704F). For some molecules it works perfectly but for some I am getting following error:  Must be real number, not str.

The input file contains SMILES extension of molecule.

```py
import sys, math, scipy.constants as sp
from collections import Counter
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolDescriptors
```

```py
def get_dielectric_constant(mol, TK, Vm, nD):
    gu2 = get_calc_gmu2(mol)
    if type(gu2) is str: return gu2
    x = alpha * gu2 / (TK * Vm)
    a = nD**2
    Delta2 = 8*a**2 + (a + x*(a+2)**2)**2
    DC = 0.25*(a + x*(a+2)**2 + math.sqrt(Delta2))
    return DC
```

```py
def get_output_line(density, Vm, nD, dc):
    if type(density) is float:
        line = '%5.3f %6.1f' %(density, Vm)
    else:
        line = '%s %s' %(str(density), str(Vm))
    if type(nD) is float:
        line += ' %6.3f' %nD
    else:
        line += ' %s' %str(nD)
    try:
        line += ' %8.4f' %dc
    except ValueError:
        line += ' %s' %str(dc)
    return line
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\c9cp01704f2\smi2DC.py", line 370, in <module>
    print(get_output_line(density, Vm, nD, dc))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\c9cp01704f2\smi2DC.py", line 340, in get_output_line
    line += ' %8.4f' %dc
TypeError: must be real number, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone have idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `dc` in `get_output_line()` might be a string, is it expected? Your code doesn't handle this case - `' %8.4f' % dc` requires `dc` to be a number.

Perhaps you meant to replace `ValueError` with a `TypeError`? Or use the same `type(...) is float` idiom for `dc` as you did for other variables?